# Error:Failed to resolve: android.support:compatibility-v4:23.1.1

Tags: android, android-support-library, mapsforge

I'm trying to add `org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map-android-extras:0.6.0` dependency to my project. But when I do it, I get this error after sync:

> Error:Failed to resolve: android.support:compatibility-v4:23.1.1

This is my *.gradle* file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.my.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 4
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map-android:0.6.0'
compile 'com.caverock:androidsvg:1.2.2-beta-1'
compile 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map-android-extras:0.6.0'

//compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Did you make sure you have the appropriate support library downloaded? If you added the compile '...' line by hand, you should go into the dependencies through your module settings to confirm you have the correct support library.

Comment: I see the line "com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1" in the dependencies tab in my module. I also reinstalled Android Support Library in SDK Tools tab in SDK Manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution from mapsforge-dev google group:

Replace

```
compile 'org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map-android-extras:0.6.0'
```

to

```
compile('org.mapsforge:mapsforge-map-android-extras:0.6.0') {
    transitive = false
}
```

The mapsforge docs will be updated.